Is it possible to run a Node.js "Passenger" App on domain root in CPanel, instead of a subdirectory?
I am trying to follow CPanel / WHMCS's directions (here and here) for setting up a Node.js app as a "passenger" app. Since CPanel has primarily been a LAMP stack, their Node offering seems a bit of a patched-on offering, and they kind of admit it is so.
Anyway, the way the option works, you must specific a subdirectory when setting up the Node app in the CPanel application manager. I tried to just go with a slash, but that didn't work. Anyone successfully running their Node app on a WHMCS / CPanel managed hosting environment and have it serve it from domain.com instead of domain.com/nodeapp/?
For the record, I am looking for something more permanent and graceful than a mod_rewrite rule.

Passenger uses autodetection algorithm, which limits possibility to host app directly in document root, but its subfolder
more: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/nodejs/app_autodetection/apache/
